# Laravel Passport - Grant Type Not Supported

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I have installed Laravel Passport per the documentation and I have modified all areas of my code that is required.

I am working on setting up Password Grant Tokens so that users will be able to get an API token when logging in with their username and password for the site.  I am hitting an issue though when it comes to the grant_type.
For some reason Laravel is complaining about an invalid grant type.

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
  "hint": "Check the `grant_type` parameter"
}
```

These are the fields that I am posting to `/oauth/token`

```
client_id = 4
client_secret = SMiYE7XqDNtXKQnmkYmFnXxfAaV83vRhnJ9zwCtZ
username = jcrawford@domain.com
password = **************
grant_type = password
scope = *
```

I have run `php artisan passport:install` and I have also tried running `php artisan passport:client --password`

Both commands worked and both created the client and secrets, however, I cannot seem to get past the error about the grant_type.

Any suggestions on what I should look at to get this solved so that Password Grant Tokens will work for me?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It appears that you must send the parameters as form data and not in the headers like I was doing... Rookie Mistake!

Comment: I currently got the same issue, I put all parameters / option in postman Headers Section, so you say I put all inside the Body section?

Comment: Correct it has to go in the body as if it were form data.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using Postman and I have put all parameters in Params. Postman shows the following response

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
    "hint": "Check the `grant_type` parameter"
}
```

Now I put all parameters in Body and then press the Send button, It's working well.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that i wasnt using `Request $request`, i was using `RegisterRequest` $request which i had created.

Comment: This was my problem too. So instead of `$request`, I ended up using `request()` so I can still validate the data with my Form Request class.

Answer (score 0):

Initial URL

```
https://restfulapi.test/oauth/authorize?client_id=3&redirect_url=http://restfulapi.test?response_type=code
```

Solution

```
https://restfulapi.test/oauth/authorize?client_id=3&redirect_url=http://restfulapi.test&response_type=code
```

I had to replace the question mark before response_type with the `&`

Comment: @SurajRao ROBO-REVIEWERS: review carefully. He's not posting a link to the solution or asking a new question (as your copy/paste text seems to suggest). He's answering the question by changing the `?` to an `&` before his `response_type` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Laravel documentation saved me a lot of stress. The `oauth\token` is used to retrieve token using the grant type specified, the route will return a JSON response containing access_token, refresh_token, and expires_in attributes. The expires_in attribute contains the number of seconds until the access token expires ([ref](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#requesting-tokens-converting-authorization-codes-to-access-tokens)) You are meant to

1. Install passport
2. Publish the service providers and migrations and migrate.
3. Setup a route for login/register to create an account and login.
4. In your User model, add `HasApiTokens` from use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
5. In your response in your login method, add the token as part of the response.
   [image]
6. Test your response on postman
   [image]